# Is it possible to start a bounty sooner than the minimum?

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to start a bounty sooner than the minimum?

I have seen 0 activity in my question and I think I could benefit from a bounty

Comment: Are you referring to the question you asked a mere 2 hours ago? Patience young grasshopper.

Comment: well as it's quite an obvious question with popular tags I was expecting some more feedback but it seems its more complicated than that.. .if you have any tips on improving it, they are very welcome!

Comment: If so, wouldn't the time before the "minimum" be the actual "minimum"?

Comment: @Wooble Oh stop it with all your logic and reason. When has that ever done anyone any good? ;)

Comment: wise-asses! :P by asking "if its possible" I'm implying "reduce the minimum" ! :D it's called being subtle  :-)

Comment: Then make something called a feature request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. But you can do something else:

**Edit your question.** By doing so, It will be pushed in the active questions queue. When editing your question keep in mind:

- Make your question title interesting but informative
- Post with the proper tags. If appropriate with high viewed tags*
- Put effort in your question, give details and avoid chatting. Too long questions scare off

<sub>* Many users watch their favorite tags</sub>

Answer (score 0):

No, you must wait the minimum 2 days before setting a bounty.

There is a 2 day minimum on starting a bounty as when a question is new, it already shows up decently high in the tag page and on the new questions list.